# MacBook Pro (13 inch, early 2015) crashing after use of Dual External Monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, crash, displayport

recently I have had a rather odd issue concerning the MacBook Pro 13 inch (early 2015) where it would crash after being unused for periods of 60-80 min when connected with a DisplayPort Cable to an external 4K display. It was plugged in every instance where it would crash. Additionally, when I disconnected the DisplayPort Cable and opened up the MacBook to use its normal display, it showed a black screen. However, the trackpad appeared the show functionality, but using the screen and keyboard brightness buttons yielded no responses.

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Have you tried testing the MBP in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) to see if the problem still occurs? Also, can you edit your question (there's an _edit_ link below it) to clarify how you're using your MBP? For example, your question title refers to _Dual External Monitor_ but your question doesn't expand on this. Are you just using the one external display, or two? It may also be worth including the exact model of your display(s).

Answer (score 1):

I am having similar issue on **iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015)**, see: [Displays randomly remain blank when waking up](https://discussions.apple.com/message/31615454)

An engineer was assigned to my case in Apple Support. I recommend getting support from Apple too.